# Pass Concatenated Variables onClick

Tags: javascript

I have this on my submit buttton

```
onClick="jsfunction('my-php.php','var1','Wait Message Here...')"
```

it passes 3 parameters to my javascript function

```
1st - my PHP File that will process the data
2nd - a variable of the data that will be processed
3rd - a wait message
```

Now I want to pass multiple variable in the 2nd parameter separated by a comma (something like this - var,var2,var3

How can I accomplish that. Thanks

Comment: Just do `('my-php.php','var1, var2, var3','Wait Message Here...')`? I'm really not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The multiple variables will be chopped in the PHP file that will process the data

Comment: What does jsfunction look like, and what does PHP expect? One string with comma separated values, or various $_GET[] keys with each their own value?

Comment: Did you really mean `'var1'`, or actually `var1`?

Answer (score 0):

To join `var1`, `var2` and `var3` into one string separated by commas, just put then in an array and join them:

```
jsfunction('my-php.php', [var1, var2, var3].join(','),'Wait Message Here...')
```

or, if you prefer, you can simply concatenate them.

```
var1 + "," + var2 + "," + var3
```